# Why does augmenting a type with undefied or null have no effect in typescript

Tags: typescript

Why are types T1, T2 and T3 equal?

```
type T1 = number
type T2 = T1 | undefined // is still just number
type T3 = T1 | null      // is still just number
```

Comment: [They aren't](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFAdgVwLYCMICcBQoksATErAgD5RooAmEAZgJYoR1QD0nUzAzlD7BmAGxFQAVmiGpMOAkWgwAzOXhRq6MVB27uvAUNHipM9NjxA)

Comment: they are when "strictNullChecks": true, is commented out. which also answers the question.

Comment: Good catch. I never turn strict off. Basically the only reason it exists as an option is to assist with gradually porting JS codebases over to TS.

Comment: me neither, that is why I was so confused ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens only when

```
"strictNullChecks": true,
```

is commented out in tsconfig. so the config affects how typescript sees types.